# Specific output for cust_valid

Tags: oracle

I need to have a customer with cust_valid "A" and cust_valid "I" (2 rows per customer).

```
select c.cust_first_name || ' ' || c.cust_last_name as customer_name,
c.cust_valid from customers c
join sales s on s.cust_id = c.cust_id
where c.cust_valid like '%A%' or
c.cust_valid like '%I%'
group by  c.cust_first_name, c.cust_last_name, c.cust_credit_limit, c.cust_valid
having sum(s.amount_sold) > c.cust_credit_limit * 500;
```

What I have as an output is all the customers which have either A or I for cust_valid. I need to output only the customers that have both (in 2 rows)

I tried using AND instead of OR but since in no row we will have both I or A it gives me an empty table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cte` for your query and `group by customer_name` so you get only the customers with both A and I in `cust_valid`:

```
with cte as (
    select c.cust_first_name || ' ' || c.cust_last_name as customer_name,
    c.cust_valid from customers c
    join sales s on s.cust_id = c.cust_id 
    where c.cust_valid like '%A%' or c.cust_valid like '%I%'
    group by  c.cust_first_name, c.cust_last_name, c.cust_credit_limit, c.cust_valid
    having sum(s.amount_sold) > c.cust_credit_limit * 500
 )
select * from cte
where customer_name in (  
  select customer_name 
  from cte
  group by customer_name
  having count(distinct cust_valid) = 2
)
```

Comment: Couldn't it return also records with 2 cust_valid A?

Comment: No, because of distict.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice, BTW isn't it more efficient to add `distinct` inside `cte`?

Comment: I have put inside the cte your query which groups by many columns, not just customer name. You need to group by customer_name only to get the customers with both A and I.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `SELF_JOIN` and also need to remove `CUST_VALID` from GROUP BY as it is different for the same customer

```
SELECT
    C.CUST_FIRST_NAME
    || ' '
    || C.CUST_LAST_NAME AS CUSTOMER_NAME,
    LISTAGG(C.CUST_VALID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.CUST_VALID) AS CUST_VALID
    -- CUST_VALID IS DIFFERENT FOR SAME CUSTOMERS SO LISTAGG IS USED TO GET ALL THE CUST_VALID
FROM
    CUSTOMERS C
    JOIN SALES S ON S.CUST_ID = C.CUST_ID
    JOIN CUSTOMERS C1 ON (C.<UNIQUE_KEYS> = C1.<UNIQUE_KEYS>)
WHERE
    C.CUST_VALID LIKE '%A%'
    AND C1.CUST_VALID LIKE '%I%' -- CONDTITION IS CHANGED TO C1
GROUP BY
    C.CUST_FIRST_NAME,
    C.CUST_LAST_NAME,
    C.CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT
    --C.CUST_VALID -- Removed it from GROUP BY
HAVING
    SUM(S.AMOUNT_SOLD) > C.CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT * 500;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: What happens when you have `cust_valid` of `ABC` and `ADE`?

Comment: Thanks MT0!! Changed my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Move the check into the `HAVING` clause and `COUNT` to make sure you have one of each row types:

```
select c.cust_first_name || ' ' || c.cust_last_name as customer_name,
       LISTAGG( c.cust_valid, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY c.cust_valid ) AS cust_valid
from   customers c
       join sales s
       on s.cust_id = c.cust_id
WHERE  c.cust_valid like '%A%'
OR     c.cust_valid like '%I%'
group by  c.cust_first_name,
       c.cust_last_name,
       c.cust_credit_limit
having sum(s.amount_sold) > c.cust_credit_limit * 500
AND    COUNT( CASE WHEN c.cust_valid like '%A%' THEN 1 END ) > 0
AND    COUNT( CASE WHEN c.cust_valid like '%I%' THEN 1 END ) > 0;
```